# Write File to Response

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller action. When the action is fired, a call is made to another URL. That all returns a .txt file. I know because I have the link in an email. WHen I click the link, a .txt file gets downloaded (which is what I want).

I need my app to be a wrapper for that. In an attempt to do this, I have the following:

```
using (var fileClient = new HttpClient())
{
  var textFile = await fileClient.GetStreamAsync(textFileUrl);
  Response.ClearContent();
  Response.ClearHeaders();

  // Now what?
}
```

I'm not sure what to do from here. I'm pretty confident that `textFile` has the text file I need. I just want to let the user download that file.

Comment: What _do_ you want to do?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I want the user to be able to download the file returned by fileClient.GetStreamAsync onto their computer. If possible, I then just want to reload the View

Comment: Well there's a `FileResult` you can return. You can't reload the view in the same response though. That's why you download things by clicking a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Returning  a file stream

```
// Specify file name
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=myFile.txt");

// Return file stream. textFile - is your file stream
return new FileStreamResult(textFile, "text/plain");
```

### Redirect to a file

```
return Redirect("http://example.com/myFile.txt");
```